# Need clarification on Coalescent with Recombination

Tags: population-genetics, recombination

I've been reading about recombination with coalescent. The link to that file is as follows:

http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/__data/assets/pdf_file/0008/4688/Reading_for_Recombination.pdf

I get the part where it says (page 142) that the rate of a coalescence event is k(k-1)/2 and the rate of recombination is kp/2. The image they have on the same page shows the intensity of coalescence and recombination. But I don't quite understand how those have been calculated. I mean the first event is a recombination event and not a coalescence event. I know they are using the rate formula I've mentioned above but I don't understand what sequences they are considering. If someone can give me a detailed answer I would really appreciate that.

I've attached the image as-well incase you don't want to read the pdf :)[image]

Comment: Can you provide citation for the now-broken link?